# Confused on how to run the Sedgewick textbook libraries

Tags: java, macos

I ran the Mac installer here:

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/

which says

The Mac OS X installer downloads algs4.jar to the /Users/username/algs4 folder; adds it to the DrJava classpath; and provides the wrapper scripts javac-algs4 and java-algs4, which classpath in algs4.jar, for use in the Terminal.

I don't see an algs4 folder created in Users/username..not sure whats going on here.

Q. What is the easiest way to execute the main() method in classes that are contained in algs4.jar?

A. If you used our autoinstaller, you can execute with a command like

```
% java-algs4 edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw
```

This command works:

```
java-algs4 edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw
```

but when i try to run

```
java-algs4 edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Counter
```

or

```
java-algs4 edu.princeton.cs.algs4.BinarySearch
```

I just get errors like:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>     at edu.princeton.cs.algs4.BinarySearch.main(BinarySearch.java:94)

Comment: Seems like these applications requires some command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try running with command line arguments that are required as input for this program.

```
java-algs4 edu.princeton.cs.algs4.BinarySearch largeW.txt < largeT.txt
```

Get the files from the downloaded data as part of your installation.
You can also refer to this [link](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/BinarySearch.java.html)